# Regex - How to include special characters in this regex

Tags: regex

I have here a regex which accepts alphanumeric characters and also single spaces only, the problem is special characters are not included in my validation, btw I'm using react for this

Here is my code

```
.matches(/^[\w]+([-_\s]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*$/i, "Invalid input, please try another value")
```

Expected: Accept all inputs but will show error if multiple spaces is inputted without trimming the value

Comment: You probably would need to define what "special characters" means here.

Comment: As an aside, `{1}` is only useful to demonstrate that you are rather new to regular expressions.

Comment: Still, please [edit] to identify which programming language or regex tool you are using, as required in the [tag:regex] tag's guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex has a symbol `\S` (note: not `\s`) which means "everything except whitespace".

If you change your regex to use `\S`, instead of using `[a-z0-9]`, that should resolve your problem.

It's also worth noting that as @tripleee stated, the `{1}` is also entirely unnecessary, so I have removed it in my answer.

```js
.matches(/^[\w]+([-_\s]\S+)*$/i, "Invalid input, please try another value")
```

Comment: Got another problem with this, The regex didn't accept If i tried adding a single space in the end, for example "Testing "

Comment: You could try the following regex: `/^[\w]+([-_\s]\S+)*\s*$/i` although I haven't tested this!